# Insert row using jdbctemplate with PrimaryKey generated by @GeneratedValue

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am inserting a row into an Oracle table in a Spring Boot application.  The Primary Key needs to be generated using annotations.  I have an entity model that represents the table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PURCH_TENDR")
public class LhlPurchTendrModel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name="PURCH_TENDR_ID")
    private String purchTendrId;

    @Column(name="CREATED_BY_NM")
    private String createdByNm;

    @Column(name="CREATED_DT")
    private Timestamp createdDt;

    @Column(name="UPDATED_BY_NM")
    private String updatedByNm;

    @Column(name="UPDATED_DT")
    private Timestamp updatedDt;

    @Column(name="MODIFY_BY_NM")
    private String modifyByNm;

    @Column(name="MODIFY_DT")
    private Timestamp modifyDt;

    @Column(name="CARRIER_TENDER_ID")
    private long CarrierTenderId;

    @Column(name="EVENT_GMT_TM")
    private Timestamp EventGmtTm;

    @Column(name="PURCH_COST_ID")
    private int PurchCostId;

    @Column(name="LAT")
    private float Lat;

    @Column(name="LON")
    private float Lon;

    @Column(name="CITY_NM")
    private String cityNm;

    @Column(name="STATE_CD")
    private String stateCd;

    @Column(name="CARER_EDI_NBR")
    private String carerEdiNbr;

    @Column(name="EVENT_STAT_CD")
    private String eventStatCd;

    @Column(name="ETN_TM")
    private Timestamp EtnTm;

    @Column(name="PCKUP_NBR")
    private String PickupNbr;

    @Column(name="VIN")
    private String Vin;

    @Column(name="EQUIP_NBR")
    private String EquipNbr;

    @Column(name="EQUIP_PREFIX")
    private String EquipPrefix;
```

There are also getters and setters for these member variables.
I use a Repository class to implements a jdbctemplate to insert the row.
When I use this variation of the insert, I get the error that the column type is invalid:

```
public boolean insertPurchaseInfo(LhlPurchTendrModel lhlPurchTendrModel) throws SQLException {
        boolean success= false;
        String ds = lhlJdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().getSchema();
        LOGGER.info("Schema and Insert Purchase Info {}", ds);
        String insertSequenceNbrSQLStatement = "INSERT INTO purch_tendr(created_by_nm, created_dt, modify_by_nm, modify_dt, carrier_tender_id, purch_cost_id, event_stat_cd, equip_nbr, equip_prefix) " +
                "VALUES (?, SYSDATE, ?, SYSDATE, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        try{
            int rowsInserted = lhlJdbcTemplate.update(
                    insertSequenceNbrSQLStatement,                
                    new Object[] {lhlPurchTendrModel});

            if(rowsInserted > 0){
                success = true;
            }
        }
```

When I try to insert using this code, I get the error 'cannot insert NULL into table Purch_Tendr column Purch_Tendr_Id.

```
public boolean insertPurchaseInfo(LhlPurchTendrModel lhlPurchTendrModel) throws SQLException {
        boolean success= false;
        String ds = lhlJdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().getSchema();
        LOGGER.info("Schema and Insert Purchase Info {}", ds);
        String insertSequenceNbrSQLStatement = "INSERT INTO purch_tendr(created_by_nm, created_dt, modify_by_nm, modify_dt, carrier_tender_id, purch_cost_id, event_stat_cd, equip_nbr, equip_prefix) " +
                "VALUES (?, SYSDATE, ?, SYSDATE, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        try{
            int rowsInserted = lhlJdbcTemplate.update(
                    insertSequenceNbrSQLStatement,                
                      new Object[]{lhlPurchTendrModel.getCreatedByNm(), lhlPurchTendrModel.getModifyByNm(), lhlPurchTendrModel.getCarrierTenderId(), lhlPurchTendrModel.getPurchCostId(),
                                lhlPurchTendrModel.getEventGmtTm(), lhlPurchTendrModel.getEquipNbr(), lhlPurchTendrModel.getEquipPrefix()});
            if(rowsInserted > 0){
                success = true;
            }
        }
```

I am not sure how to use the @Entity class with JdbcTemplate.  How do I indicate to JdbcTemplate to generate the primary key value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because `@Entity` and all annotations you use such as `@GeneratedValue`, `@GenericGenerator` etc come from  `JPA` while `JdbcTemplate` behind scene is based on JDBC only which does not know anything about JPA.

If you want to use JPA to manage your data , what you need to look is to choose a JPA implementation (e.g Hibernate is a popular one) and study how to use it through JPA interface but not looking at `JdbcTemplate`.

Once you get the basic ideas to manage data using JPA , you may consider to look at spring data which is a more high level tool build on top of pure JPA that can help to implement repository / DAO kind of stuff for managing and querying the data.

Comment: Thanks! Darn.  That will mean changing a lot of stuff. Is there any other way to generate UUID values using jdbc?

Comment: Can you simply use `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` in Java to get an UUID first and insert a new record like a simple JDCB insert statement using JBDCTemplate ?

Comment: What's the difference between that generated value in the value generated by JPA?

Comment: not sure about the detail about the ID generate the Hibernate UUID , but if what you want is to just get random ID , `UUID.randomUUID()` is also a safe option to go